# kibana - metricbeat dashboard for multiple hosts

Tags: kibana

Im new to kibana but am hoping to migrate away from Datadog. In DD I can create 'visualizations' that are specific to a single data source (host in this case) and combine several into one dashboard.

EG: view CPU load for n hosts on one page

Am not seeing (yet) how to accomplish this sort of thing via Kibana.

Suggestions on where to look?

Using v6.x Kibana/logstash/elasticsearch/metricbeat

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is achievable using Visual Builder visualization

See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/6.1/time-series-visualizations.html

Aggregate `Max` or `Avg` on `system.cpu.total.pct`

Group By `Terms` By `beat.hostname.keyword`

The visualization will show CPU usage in % for all hosts sending metrics to your cluster. If you add more hosts those will show up too!

Comment: your solution is so much easier than mine! :)

Answer (score 2):

To get you started: Create a timelion expression:

```
.es(index=metricbeat-*, metric='avg:system.process.cpu.total.pct',split='beat.name:10').trim().fit(scale).multiply(1000).movingaverage(5).label(label='cpu usage % : ',regex='.*name.*:').label(label='',regex='>.*')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just to illustrate @ben5556's answer with an image.

[image: ss]

#### Legend

1. Aggregation set to `Max`
2. Field to collect data from `system.process.summary.total`
3. How to group by `Term`
4. What to group by (the "Term") - `beat.hostname`
5. How to order these terms - order by the `Term`

**NOTE:** The "Term" is `beat.hostname`.